# Rest API and Custom Fields

Tags: rest-api

how can I create a new post post (custom type, with custom fields) on the front end using rest api and an http request? Is this even currently possible to create a new post with custom fields through a POST request? I cant seem to find a solid either way.

I have been developing a site using the core rest api. I have a custom post type that's using custom fields. I have the custom fields registered in the functions.php with a get_callback and update_callback. Currently I can GET results fine, and I can POST a new custom post but only the title. Any input for the custom fields is not passed to the server, they just go no where.

So is this possible? I can post the code I'm using but I just wanted to check first.

Thanks

Comment: you can try that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940238/add-post-meta-fields-via-wp-api-v2/#answer-46962161